# Can I overload the {} dictionary definition meta-characters/operator for a particular python namespace?

Tags: python-2.7

Can I overload the {} dictionary definition meta-characters/operator for a particular python namespace?

What I am asking is how to (in pure python), replace the type({}) == dict with type({}) == instance && isinstance({}, MyDict) == True.

I have a configuration file in python syntax. I'd the user to be able to define dictionaries, but I want to guarantee the order of the dictionary items are the same as the user put them in the code. I figured the only way this could be done is if I could overload the syntactic sugar surrounding {} dictionary declaration characters.

If it can't be done, that'd be a OK answer.

Thanks,
Chenz

Comment: Would an OrderedDict be what you're looking for? http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary literals are created by the compiler (or rather, the compiler emits bytecode to create them directly). If you want to override this then you'll need to compile the source into into bytecode yourself and then iterate through the bytecode, replacing the dict creation with a bytecode sequence of your choosing.